# How to strip prefix from envoy route?

Tags: envoyproxy

I have front end application serving at 127.0.0.1:8080/home and I am trying to configure envoy to route to my front end app at [www.domain.com/foo/home](http://www.domain.com/foo/home), but currently only work with trailing slash at the end.

[www.domain.com/foo/home/](http://www.domain.com/foo/home/) -> 127.0.0.1:8080/home OK

[www.domain.com/foo/home](http://www.domain.com/foo/home) -> 127.0.0.1:8080/home NOT FOUND

How I can configure envoy to strip last slash at path and handle all possible cases when routing? As I understand I need two cases to handle it https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v3/config/route/v3/route_components.proto#envoy-v3-api-field-config-route-v3-routeaction-prefix-rewrite
Here is my basic configuration:

```
    admin:
  address:
    socket_address: { address: 0.0.0.0, port_value: 9901 }
static_resources:
  listeners:
  - name: listener_0
    address:
      socket_address:
        address: 0.0.0.0
        port_value: 10000
    filter_chains:
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
          stat_prefix: ingress_http
          access_log:
          - name: envoy.access_loggers.stdout
            typed_config:
              "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.access_loggers.stream.v3.StdoutAccessLog
          http_filters:
          - name: envoy.filters.http.router
            typed_config:
              "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.router.v3.Router
          route_config:
            name: local_route
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: local_service
              domains: ["*"]
              routes:
              - match: { prefix: "/foo/", case_sensitive: false }
                route:
                  prefix_rewrite: "/"
                  cluster: angular_app
              - match: { prefix: "/foo", case_sensitive: false }
                route:
                  prefix_rewrite: "/"
                  cluster: angular_app

  clusters:
  - name: angular_app
    type: STATIC
    load_assignment:
      cluster_name: angular_app
      endpoints:
      - lb_endpoints:
        - endpoint:
            address:
              socket_address:
                address: 127.0.0.1
                port_value: 8080
```